# Fit background image into second background image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've got two images - a frame and the image which should fit exactly into that frame. The thing which makes it really hard is the **responsiveness**.

**Two images:**

[image]

What it should look like (also after resizing):

[image]

**What I've tried:**

```
.brawler.shelly {
    background-image: url("/images/heroes/high/hero_icon_shelly.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 85%;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.portrait {
    background-image: url("/images/icons/card_common.png");
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.col-4.col-md-3.col-lg-2.mb-2
    .portrait
        .brawler.shelly

.col-4.col-md-3.col-lg-2.mb-2
    .portrait
        .brawler.shelly
```

**JSfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/3z68kcbr/

Comment: Don't have time to help further, but play with a relative and absolute boxes, and use background size cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just play around with the `background-size` and `padding-bottom` on `.brawler.shelly`?

`background-size: 77%` and `padding-bottom: 106%` seems to work pretty well for me:

```css
.brawler.shelly {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/vuv5sdZ.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 77%;
  padding-bottom: 106%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.portrait {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/i2IoHtw.png");
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-2">
    <div class="portrait">
      <div class="brawler shelly">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This also has no issue with responsiveness. I've created a fiddle of this **[over here](https://jsfiddle.net/7kbpnd2z/)** if you'd like to test how it resizes.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, `background-position`

CSS

```
.brawler.shelly {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/vuv5sdZ.png);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 86%;
    padding-bottom: 104%;
    position: sticky;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.portrait {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/i2IoHtw.png");
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 mb-2">
         <div class="portrait">
            <div class="brawler shelly">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prasangakarunanayake/3z68kcbr/5/)

Comment: That won't work because of the static height - responsiveness is important!